# Find key in array in a foreach

Tags: php, arrays

I have this foreach function:

```
foreach($total_data as $arrays){        

                //debug
                //print_r($total_data);
                //exit;

                if($arrays['code']=='d_payment_fee'){
                    $dpaymentfeetext = ' - '.$arrays['title'];
                    $dpaymentfeevalue = $arrays['value']/1.20;
                }

                if($arrays['code']=='shipping'){

                            $api->addItem(array( 
                                    'name' => $arrays['title'].$dpaymentfeetext,
                                    'quantity' => 1,
                                    'unit' => 'ks',
                                    'unit_price' => ($arrays['value']+$dpaymentfeevalue)*1.20
                            ));
                    }
            }
```

This works fine, if the first array item is the d_payment_fee, and the second is the shipping:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [order_total_id] => 214950
        [order_id] => 4779
        [code] => d_payment_fee
        [title] => COD
        [text] => 1,00€
        [value] => 1.0000
        [sort_order] => 2
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [order_total_id] => 214951
        [order_id] => 4779
        [code] => shipping
        [title] => Free
        [text] => 0,00€
        [value] => 0.0000
        [sort_order] => 3
    )
```

There are cases when **d_payment_fee** is not on the first place, like here:

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [order_total_id] => 216352
            [order_id] => 4796
            [code] => shipping
            [title] => Free shipping
            [text] => 2,50€
            [value] => 2.5000
            [sort_order] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [order_total_id] => 216353
            [order_id] => 4796
            [code] => d_payment_fee
            [title] => COD
            [text] => 1,00€
            [value] => 1.0000
            [sort_order] => 3
        )
```

In this case I got undefined variable $dpaymentfee*.
Can we find the **d_payment_fee** if it is not on the first place?

Comment: What does your original array look like?

Comment: There are several more items, but these two are relevants to me. If you need, I can copy here.

Comment: as a side note, you might consider using `else if` on your second condition

Comment: What value should $dpaymentfe be if d_payment_fee isn't in the first array?  Or must the  d_payment_fee condition (where $dpaymentfe is defined) occur before shipping?

Comment: I must first search for d_payment_fee in the array (even if it's on first or last place), only then run if($arrays['code']=='shipping') statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always loop through the array twice and break out of the first loop once you find the d_payment_fee code:

```
$dpaymentfeetext = '';
$dpaymentfeevalue = '';

foreach ($total_data as $data)
{
    if ($data['code'] == 'd_payment_fee')
    {
        $dpaymentfeetext = ' - '.$data['title'];
        $dpaymentfeevalue = $data['value']/1.20;
        break;
    }
}

// Then do your original loop here
```

Answer (score 2):

Call `addItem` outside of the loop, after you find all the values you need.

```
$fees_found = false;
$shipping_found = false;
foreach($total_data as $arrays){        

    if($arrays['code']=='d_payment_fee'){
        $dpaymentfeetext = ' - '.$arrays['title'];
        $dpaymentfeevalue = $arrays['value']/1.20;
        $fees_found = true;
    }

    elseif($arrays['code']=='shipping'){
        $title = $arrays['title'];
        $value = $arrays['value'];
        $shipping_found = true;
    }
    // Stop once we've found everything needed
    if ($fees_found && $shipping_found) {
        break;
    }

}        
$api->addItem(array( 
                    'name' => $title.$dpaymentfeetext,
                    'quantity' => 1,
                    'unit' => 'ks',
                    'unit_price' => ($value+$dpaymentfeevalue)*1.20
                     ));
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not so good for performance but it can solve the problem.

```
$index = 0;
        $dpaymentfeetextArray = array();
        $dpaymentfeevalueArray = array();
        foreach ($total_data as $arrays) {
            if ($arrays['code'] == 'd_payment_fee') {
                $dpaymentfeetextArray[$index] = ' - ' .$arrays['title'];
                $dpaymentfeevalueArray[$index] = $arrays['value']/1.20;
                $index++;
            }
        }
        $index = 0;
        foreach ($total_data as $arrays) {
            if ($arrays['code'] == 'shipping') {
                 $api->addItem(array(
                        'name'          => $arrays['title'] .(isset($dpaymentfeetextArray[$index]) ? $dpaymentfeetextArray[$index] : ' '),
                        'quantity'      => 1,
                        'unit'          => 'ks',
                        'unit_price'    => ($arrays['value'] + (isset($dpaymentfeevalueArray[$index]) ? $dpaymentfeevalueArray[$index] : 0))*1.20
                ));
                $index++;
            }
        }
```